# Getting List of user's followers in Django Social Media project

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

In my project I am trying to show a list of other user's followers and following. Right now it only has the requesting user's. Here are my models and views:

**Models**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='profile', 
                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
followers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='following', blank=True)
```

**Views**

```
class FollowersPageView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Profile
    paginate_by = 20
    template_name = 'users/followers.html'
    context_object_name = 'users'

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        return self.request.user.profile.followers.all()

class FollowingPageView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = User
    paginate_by = 20
    template_name = 'users/following.html'
    context_object_name = 'profiles'

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        return self.request.user.following.all()
```

**URLS**

```
**(Old url)**
re_path(r'^u/followers$', users_views.FollowersPageView.as_view(), 
       name='view_all_followers'),
**(New url)**
re_path(r'^u/(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/followers$', 
       users_views.FollowersPageView.as_view(), name='view_all_followers'),
```

I was trying to change the get_queryset of FollowersPageView to the following but was getting error messages:

```
def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
    user_username = self.kwargs['username']
    user_followers = Profile.objects.filter(followers=user_username)
    return user_followers
```

Thank you

Comment: Show us your error traceback..

Comment: The error is: ValueError at /u/jsmith/followers
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'jsmith'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()


def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
    user_username = self.kwargs['username']
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=user_username)
    user_followers = user.followers.all()
    return user_followers
```